# AWS Lambda Function for AWS Codepipeline

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline

As the windows docker does not provide DIND or docker commands inside my docker, I am trying to setup my CI environment a little different.

I need to invoke a lambda function in the pipeline. For this, I created a lambda and set it in the code pipeline. But instead of my success, pipeline shows as the timeout.

I didn't find any proper article or blog post to use Lamda in the dot net core as a sample. The following is my Lamda code:

```
    public class Function
{
    public class CodePipelineInput
    {
        [JsonProperty("CodePipeline.job")]
        public Job job { get; set; }
    }
    public async Task FunctionHandler(CodePipelineInput source, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        var codepipeline = new AmazonCodePipelineClient();
            var putJobSuccessRequestResult = new PutJobSuccessResultRequest()
            {
                JobId = source.job.Id
            };
            await codepipeline.PutJobSuccessResultAsync(putJobSuccessRequestResult);
    }
}
```

Please guide me or share some blogs/articles related to this

Answer (score 0):

Please check two things:

1. Lambda function execution role should have "codepipeline:PutJobSuccessResult" and "codepipeline:PutJobFailureResult" permissions as described in our documentation [1].
2. Lambda function should have code that returns the job result to CodePipeline. Please find the description of PutJobSuccessResultRequest method here [2] and some code example for C# here [3].

Ref:

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-invoke-lambda-function.html#actions-invoke-lambda-function-create-function

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=CodePipeline/MCodePipelinePutJobSuccessResultPutJobSuccessResultRequest.html

[3] https://github.com/PaulDMendoza/aws-unzip-codepipeline-output-lambda/blob/master/Function.cs

Comment: Thanks, mate. Unfortunately still not working. I have given Full code pipeline permission to the lambda function execution role as well as code pipeline role. Anyway thanks for the last article. That makes a hint to advance...will look

Comment: Found the root cause: I gave VPC, Subnets and security groups and it causes the issue. If I removed these, Lamda executed successfully. Verifying the reason

Comment: The obvious reason could be that Lambda can't reach CodePipeline endpoint (based on region, e.g. codepipeline.us-east-1.amazonaws.com) when VPC option is provided. Check if your subnet has route to 0.0.0.0/0 via internet gateway or nat gateway.